# Make window draggable on certain element/grid | C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a custom title bar and I'm struggling with the window drag function. This question is clearly not a duplicate...

My Grid:

```
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="TitleBar" Panel.ZIndex="1" MouseLeftButtonDown="WindowDrag">
        
        <StackPanel Height="30" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"   
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button Width="30" Style="{StaticResource DisabledButton}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Ellipse Fill="#00CA4E" Width="10" Height="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

        </StackPanel>
```

I've also tried adding `MouseLeftButtonDown` to the StackPanel it didn't work either.

My Code:

```
    private void WindowDrag(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         this.DragMove();
    }
```

Comment: Probably it is because you have not set Background of the Grid. If so, Background is null and hit test will not work.

Comment: Thanks it worked @emoacht, such a beginner mistake from me. Have a good day!